# Mac OSX CyberDuck Upload Failed

Tags: ssh, retropie

I'm running RetroPie on my Raspberry Pi and need to transfer over some roms. I user CyberDuck to ssh into my raspberry pi. Lately though when I try to transfer over files I get an error telling me upload failed but it says there is no error code. I am not sure what to do if someone could please help or suggest another program (Windows or Mac) that I could use to transfer files that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: it depends on what errors you got. Maybe permission issue or timestamp errors. You can look at your auth.log file on RetroPie to understand what could go wrong.

Comment: enable logging and debugging for cyberduck. 
https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/faq#Enabledebuglogging

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to transfer files is `ssh` and copy on the command line.

You could install `netatalk` which lets you mount the Pi on `OSX` as afp://piIPaddress and access via `Finder`

1) On Pi: `sudo apt-get install netatalk`
2) On mac, open connection in Terminal / iTerm: `open afp://piIPaddress`
3) On mac, open Finder, you should see the Pi mounted

Comment: Is this really the _easiest_ way to transfer files? What about sftp?

Comment: @Bex - no its not easiest but no one said anything about easiest. Also, this is good practice to use the command line as this is how most linux programs/libraries are installed/run. It builds character :)

Comment: Well, Milliways did say "easiest". ;) And sftp is a great command line tool.

Comment: The OP was using `ssh` and having problems with `CyberDuck`. It is easier to use command line. Do these comments really add to the issue or help others?

Comment: +1 on installing netatalk. I couldn't get scp or sftp to work correctly. But netatalk made the Pi just another drive in Finder

Answer (score 0):

I created a program in c called `Sharemounter` which allows you mount a MAX OS share or Windows Share without exposing your password. Once mounted, you can transfer files.

[Github Sharemounter](https://github.com/PhillyNJ/Sharemounter)

SSH in to your Pi and enter

```
sudo apt-get install gcc

sudo git clone https://github.com/PhillyNJ/Sharemounter.git

cd Sharemounter
```

Create a config file and save it (there are examples when you get a copy from git)

```
type=mac
ip=192.168.X.X/OSX_Share_Name
folder=/home/pi/passport
username=OSX_UserName
```

To compile the code:

```
sudo make
```

Make the file executable:

```
sudo chmod + sharemounter
```

To execute:

```
sudo ./sharemounter /path/to/config/file
```

Your should see something like this:

```
Mounting 192.168.X.X from XXXX on /home/pi/XXXX Mounting of volume
XXXX of server XXXXX succeeded.
```

There are examples for how to mount to either a MAC or Windows PC. A detailed tutorial is on the [Wiki Page](https://github.com/PhillyNJ/Sharemounter/wiki)